# Pass String to webview and display

Tags: android, html, webview

I am trying to pass versionName string to webview and display the string on the page in my html. Here is what I have tried.

```
try {
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String versionName = getPackageManager()
                            .getPackageInfo("com.chad.flashupdate", 0)
                            .versionName;
    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:init('" + versionName + "')");
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then I tried to load and display the string using this.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() { $("#MyEdit").html(versionName); });
```

In my html I put this.

```
<div id="MyEdit"><B>
 versionName will be displayed here!
</B></div>
```

When I try that nothing happens, meaning the div text never changes. So maybe the webview is not loading the string. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not need javascript for this. Try this instead:

```
String htmlString = "<div id='MyEdit'><b>VERSION NAME</b></div>";
webView.loadData(htmlString, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: One more question. When I load the webview it only shows the div. How can I load the normal html file in the assets and have that div change to the the htmlString? When I add your code it only shows that div on load.

Comment: That makes things a bit more complex. There are ways to load html from a file, but putting your version into would be more complex. Here is a link for getting the asset file as a string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110002/read-assets-file-as-string. After that, I would look for a certain text character then replace that with the version you have.

Comment: This is not a correct answer to the question asked.

Comment: How so @doctorram? It is doing what the question had asked? Do you want a javascript bridge answer?

Comment: @DroidChris the question was how to pass a string parameter to HTML.  Your answer initiates WebView from a string.  Almost completely unrelated to the question!

Comment: @doctorram I am simply stating to parse a variable then make into HTML. Then you can load into a web view. If you want it to display the name, the HTML code I gave you would work. Javascript does not loadURL with a javascript command in it.