# I have no clue as how to set string path

Tags: android, fonts, assets, libraries

I am using a third party library for splash screen. I got it from https://github.com/ViksaaSkool/AwesomeSplash. I have followed the whole tutorial but i am getting error while setting string path. It has a line 
"configSplash.setPathSplash(SyncStateContract.Constants.DROID_LOGO); //set path String". Android studio is unable to resolve DROID_LOGO and i am getting error. I replaced DROID_LOGO with DATA and got this error.
As suggested on the post i have written this code.

```
public class splashex extends AwesomeSplash {

//DO NOT OVERRIDE onCreate()!
//if you need to start some services do it in initSplash()!


@Override
public void initSplash(ConfigSplash configSplash) {

        /* you don't have to override every property */

    //Customize Circular Reveal
    configSplash.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimary); //any color you want form colors.xml
    configSplash.setAnimCircularRevealDuration(2000); //int ms
    configSplash.setRevealFlagX(Flags.REVEAL_RIGHT);  //or Flags.REVEAL_LEFT
    configSplash.setRevealFlagY(Flags.REVEAL_BOTTOM); //or Flags.REVEAL_TOP

    //Choose LOGO OR PATH; if you don't provide String value for path it's logo by default

    //Customize Logo
    configSplash.setLogoSplash(R.mipmap.ic_launcher); //or any other drawable
    configSplash.setAnimLogoSplashDuration(2000); //int ms
    configSplash.setAnimLogoSplashTechnique(Techniques.Bounce); //choose one form Techniques (ref: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations)


    //Customize Path
    configSplash.setPathSplash(SyncStateContract.Constants.DROID_LOGO); //set path String(**I am getting error here**)
    //     configSplash.setOriginalHeight(400); //in relation to your svg (path) resource
    configSplash.setOriginalWidth(400); //in relation to your svg (path) resource
    configSplash.setAnimPathStrokeDrawingDuration(3000);
    configSplash.setPathSplashStrokeSize(3); //I advise value be <5
    configSplash.setPathSplashStrokeColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark); //any color you want form colors.xml
    configSplash.setAnimPathFillingDuration(3000);
    configSplash.setPathSplashFillColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark); //path object filling color


    //Customize Title
    configSplash.setTitleSplash("My Awesome App");
    configSplash.setTitleTextColor(R.color.colorAccent);
    configSplash.setTitleTextSize(30f); //float value
    configSplash.setAnimTitleDuration(3000);
    configSplash.setAnimTitleTechnique(Techniques.FlipInX);
    configSplash.setTitleFont("fonts/myfont.ttf"); //provide string to your font located in assets/fonts/

}

@Override
public void animationsFinished() {

    //transit to another activity here
    //or do whatever you want
}
```

}

The error i am getting is

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/myfont.ttf
  at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:190)
```

I searched various links and all suggested to add assets folder but i dont know where to make assets folder and what to store in that.
please help me with all the details about assets and fonts.

Still i am getting this.

[image: added the font folder still i am getting the same error.]

Comment: Please provide some example code to make sure about your solution ?

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: May Be you don't have appropriate string for setTitleFont so you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110002/read-assets-file-as-string to get String

Comment: And make sure to you have a fonts folder in assets and font which you want to set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create folder named  **fonts**  according to the following path:

**your_android_project_folder > app > src > main > assets > fonts**

Now within your **fonts** folder,you need to store your ***myfont.ttf*** file.

[image]

Comment: I can see image asset and vector asset in the options.Which should i choose.?

Comment: @Vipin You will also find a option to create directory in there.Just create a directory named fonts.

Comment: Done. But since i am using third party library i don't have myfonts.ttf. May you guide me as how can i get that.?

Comment: Check this : https://github.com/ViksaaSkool/AwesomeSplash/tree/master/app/src/main/assets/fonts . You can copy any of the .ttf files to your fonts folder,and use that particular font file in your code.

Comment: I had tried this but of no use. If i use diti_sweet.ttf from there what should i use to replace DROID_LOGO. Since this ttf file is not opening.

Comment: What is the splashx.java class for? What error are you specificially getting when trying to use the font file?Did you check with other font files?

Comment: DROID_LOGO is not getting resolved. I pasted all the fonts file still the DROID_LOGO is showing errors. I don't have any idea what kind of string DROID_LOGO is.

Comment: click on "Constatnts" in the line : configSplash.setPathSplash(SyncStateContract.Constants.DROID_LOGO);  and type Ctrl+B .It will take you to the file where Contants is declared.Then you need to create DROID_LOGO in there

Comment: Check the DROID_LOGO in here : https://github.com/ViksaaSkool/AwesomeSplash/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/viksaa/ssspalsh/util/Constants.java       . This DROID_LOGO can't be recognized for some reason.Try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: It worked. I created Constants class and wrote the same code and it worked. Thanks man. Since i have very less points my upvote won't count. Still upvoting.

Comment: No problem.Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124842/discussion-between-vipin-and-ayan).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is how I solved it :

1. For the missing DROID_LOGO, you can rewrite the line from this:

   configSplash.setPathSplash(SyncStateContract.Constants.DROID_LOGO);

to this :

```
configSplash.setPathSplash(SyncStateContract.Constants.DROID_LOGO);
```

Here, make sure you add to your project the Constants.java class which can be found [here](https://github.com/ViksaaSkool/AwesomeSplash/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/viksaa/ssspalsh/util/Constants.java)

2. And for the missing font, go to the line

   configSplash.setTitleFont("fonts/myfont.ttf"); //provide string to your font located in assets/fonts/

and replace myfont.ttf with another font present in your assets/font folder for example fonts/diti_sweet.ttf(which can be found on the [AwesomeSplash](https://github.com/ViksaaSkool/AwesomeSplash) repository) and averything might work fine

Answer (score 0):

Comment out this line:

```
configSplash.setPathSplash(SyncStateContract.Constants.DROID_LOGO);
```

and rename `myfont.ttf` to your font in folder assets.