# How to pase local JSON and populate a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I'm confused about how to parse local Json. I tried alot, but I can't find a solution.
I want to populate an ArrayList which contains just a simple title - I want to add that tite from JSON to a RecylerView.

```
{
    "hollywood": [{
        "_id": "58d3264f93f24d2bc87bebf5",
        "title": "sagar rana",
        "image": "encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/...",
        "genre": "hollywood",
        "description": "This for only demo purpose",
        "release": 2010,
        "download": "No download",
        "youtube": "youtube.com/embed/C-5EOd8xavw...",
        "__v ": 0,
        "upload ": "2017-03-23T01:35:11.182Z"
    }]
}
```

MainActivty.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import static android.R.attr.data;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    MyAdapter recycleradapter;
    private ArrayList<Moviedemo> mArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
            JSONArray m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray("hollywood");
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> formList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> m_li;

            for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("Details-->", jo_inside.getString("hollywood"));
                String formula_value = jo_inside.getString("hollywood");
                String url_value = jo_inside.getString("url");

                //Add your values in your `ArrayList` as below:
                m_li = new HashMap<String, String>();
                m_li.put("formule", formula_value);
                m_li.put("url", url_value);

                formList.add(m_li);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        recycleradapter = new MyAdapter(mArrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleradapter);

        recyclerViewstart();
        loadJSONFromAsset();


    }

    private String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {

            InputStream is = getAssets().open("homepage.json");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;


    }

    private void recyclerViewstart() {
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recylce);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    }
}
```

Comment: {
  "hollywood": [
    {
      "_id": "58d3264f93f24d2bc87bebf5",
      "title": "sagar rana",
      "image": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRGIS3UlHSRvHFV6fm8kOS5HsXI3BIY8oO1HgxHpmu2dYO6ci3-9A",
      "genre": "hollywood",
      "description": "This for only demo purpose",
      "release": "2010",
      "download": "No download",
      "youtube": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/C-5EOd8xavw",
      "__v": 0,
      "upload": "2017-03-23T01:35:11.182Z"
    }
  ]

Comment: You can use Gson for parsing the json

Comment: @BhupinderSingh add it the post not as comment

Comment: i am new to json

Comment: JSON isn't that difficult, so where exactly is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is your adapter.

```
recycleradapter = new MyAdapter(mArrayList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleradapter);
```

You never initialized `mArrayList`... so do that first

```
mArrayList = new ArrayList<Moviedemo>();
```

Then, you'll want to add to that list after to determine what you want to parse in the JSON.

You have shown you know how to get an array and a string already.

> I want to add title from json to recyler view

Just the title? As a string? Then why does the adapter hold a whole `Moviedemo` object?

```
// Set the adapter
recycleradapter = new MyAdapter(mArrayList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleradapter);

// Open and parse file
try {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
    JSONArray m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray("hollywood");

    for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
        // Start an object
        Moviedemo movie = new Moviedemo();

        // Parse the JSON
        JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);
        String title = jo_inside.getString("title");

        // Build the object
        movie.setTitle(title);

        // Add the object to the list
        mArrayList.add(movie);
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStacktrace();
}

// Update adapter
recycleradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

As have been shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110002/read-assets-file-as-string), this should do it:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
InputStream json = getAssets().open("book/contents.json");
BufferedReader in =
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(json, "UTF-8"));
String str;

while ((str=in.readLine()) != null) {
  buf.append(str);
}

in.close();
```

and the you could do something like this to parse it:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

using the `org.json`library which can be found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/1.5-20090211)

Comment: Android has built-in `org.json`, so mvnrepository not necessary. https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: that's true, I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method

```
    private JSONObject getAssetJSON() {
        String inFile = "fileName.json";
        JSONObject assetJson = null;
        try {
            InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open(inFile);
            int size = stream.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            stream.read(buffer);
            stream.close();
            String assetString = new String(buffer);
            assetJson = new JSONObject(assetString);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Handle IO exceptions here
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // Handle JSON exceptions here
        }
       return assetJson;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with JSON is a most important step for any Android Application.
As of my suggestion try learning about GSON Library.

These are some helpful links where you can have a better understanding of it.
1 . [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-getting-started-with-java-json-serialization-deserialization) , 
2. [this](http://guides.codepath.com/android/leveraging-the-gson-library)